# Setear Webhook para Whatsapp

Tags: genexus, webhook

**GX17u6**

**Generador Chatbot**

Quiero crear un chatbot en la [Plataforma de WhatsApp Business](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/?locale=es_LA)
y pasarle un webhook generado desde GX.

En la configuración pide en forma obligatoria la url y un token de verificación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De que forma se resuelve esta validación para un webhook creado por GX?

Answer (score 1):

Logré validarlo a continuación les cuento como:

Según la [doc que publica meta](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#verification-requests)
Se reciben 3 valores en el request y hay que devolver el valor recibido en  "hub.challenge".

1. Desde GX extraigo el valor "hub.challenge" de `&HttpRequest.QueryString` y lo seteo a una variable `&HubChallenge`
2. En una variable le agrego ese valor `&httpResponse.AddString(&HubChallenge)`

El valor Hub.Challenge  es como el nro de invocación del webhook y desde la API WhatsApp se espera recibirlo para dar como válido el webhook

**Estaría genial que desde Genexus estos mecanismos sean automatizados facilitando al programador estos detalles**